# problemas al consumir una api HttpErrorResponse en angular

Tags: json, angular, http, jsonobject, framework7

mi problema es que tengo una api local que levante con xampp, composer y symfony y al querer consultar la informacion que trae la misma con angular, tengo  errores del HttpErrorResponse, lo cual no entiendo a que se debe

en primer lugar cree un servicio en angular para hacer la consulta http

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Pizza } from 'app/models/pizza';



@Injectable()

export class PizzaService {
    constructor (private _http:HttpClient){
     
        
    }

   getAll():Observable <any>{
       return this._http.get<any> ('/products/list')
   }
}
```

luego lo que hice fue crear el componente que va a hacer uso de la misma

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { PizzaService } from 'app/services/pizza.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pizza',
  templateUrl: './pizza.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pizza.component.css'],
  providers: [PizzaService]

})
export class PizzaComponent implements OnInit {
  title= 'proxy';
  constructor(
    private route:ActivatedRoute, 
    private _pizzaservice: PizzaService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
  
  this._pizzaservice.getAll().subscribe(response => console.log(response))
  
}
  



}
```

el error de consola es el que inserto en la imagen
[image: HttpErrorResponse]

ya antes realice una configuracion en mi proxy.json

```js
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target":" http://127.0.0.1:8000",
        "secure":false,
        "logLevel":"debug"
    }
}
```

y a su vez en package.json  donde aplico ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

```js
{
  "name": "web-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: creo que tu error esta en el servicio que no indicas la url completa para la consulta de tu api local

Answer (score 0):

El error que muestra tu respuesta es 404, es decir que lo encuentra.

te muestro como haría yo mi servicio

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Pizza } from 'app/models/pizza';



@Injectable()

export class PizzaService {

urlApi:string="http://127.0.0.1:8000";

    constructor (private _http:HttpClient){}

   getAll():Observable <any>{
       return this._http.get<any> (`${this.urlApi}/products/list`)
   }
}
```

en la variable `apiUrl` la puedes declarar en los `enviroment` y queda accesible en toda tu aplicación o cualquier otro servicio que quieras implementar

puede ser que tu api este en una carpeta especifica y debas definirla tambien, ejemplo `apiUrl:string="http://http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"`

Comment: ahora el error de consola paso a ser el siguiente:

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list', ok: false, …}

Comment: en conjunto con este: 

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/list' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 

podria ser un error de la api directamente?

Comment: @alejandrodelgado El error de cors que estas obteniendo es por que estas haciendo la petición a `127.0.0.1:8000` y al no ser (según el navegador) el mismo sitio que `localhost:4200` la conexión se bloquea por seguridad. Por el momento puedes evitarlo cambiando la url de tu servicio a `locahost:8000`

Comment: @alejandrodelgado solucionaste tu problema con el CORS en tu API?